# Find the difference between two dates and date are stored in string type

Tags: java

I have made an application in java where I have form which has "From date" & "To date".
I want to check whether the selected date from "To date" is coming after the "From date" 
Example: If the date selected from "From date" is 2013-03-18(YY-mm-dd) then the date selected from the "To date" should be any date after/greater than 2013-03-18. To get the date i have used JXDatePicker, and to convert the date in yy-mm-dd format i have used
 `SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")`
I need this to validate, So if the "To date" is > "From date" then it should display the JOptionPane with error message.

Edit> I have tried getting the date from the JXDatePicker in the

```
Date fd = (Date) from.getDate();
```

and this is executed when the date is selected from the JXDatePicker , also i have tried printing the date, But when I run the application I am getting error as follows:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
    at rejectionCategorisedReport$1.actionPerformed(rejectionCategorisedReport.java:154)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker.fireActionPerformed(JXDatePicker.java:916)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker.commitEdit(JXDatePicker.java:706)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.basic.BasicDatePickerUI.commit(BasicDatePickerUI.java:859)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.basic.BasicDatePickerUI$Handler.monthViewActionPerformed(BasicDatePickerUI.java:1327)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.basic.BasicDatePickerUI$Handler.actionPerformed(BasicDatePickerUI.java:1302)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.fireActionPerformed(JXMonthView.java:1788)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.commitSelection(JXMonthView.java:1686)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.basic.BasicMonthViewUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMonthViewUI.java:2053)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone please help me and tell me what the problem is ?

Comment: you method is currect!

Comment: [`java.util.Date#before`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before(java.util.Date)) and [`java.util.Date#after`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after(java.util.Date)). Pick your favorite and go.

Comment: Why would you want to convert *to* a string representation? And why would you expect a `SimpleDateFormat` with a format of "yyyy/MM/dd" to give you a format of "yy-mm-dd"? It's not clear why you're trying to use a string format at all.

Comment: So you are asking us to give the complete code or what?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate - the OP doesn't *have* a string to start with, he has a `JXDatePicker`. Part of the problem (IMO) is that he's *thinking* of strings when there's no reason to.

Comment: I was having problem while storing date in database so as last option I choose to store the date in string format. The JXDatePicker was giving me output in different format then what I wanted. If theirs still a chance I would like to store it in date format but my project is ready to deliver, but this validation problem has to be first solved.

Comment: @Mayur: Well you can still *store* the date as a string if you really, really want to - although I'd strongly advise against it. That doesn't mean you need to treat it as a string for the rest of your code though. Don't let one bad decision lead to further ones. (I'd strongly recommend that you go back and fix the database instead, using an appropriate date-related field. You could post the details as a different question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'd give my normal advice of using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) wherever you possibly can. The built-in date/time API is *horrible* and easy to get very confused with.

Secondly, avoid string representations if you possibly can. Nothing you've said in your requirements indicates that you *need* a string representation - so don't create one. In general, convert *from* string representations into more sensible ones as early as you can, and convert *to* string representations as late as you can. Sticking with `LocalDate`, `DateTime` etc (or even `Date` and `Calendar`) for as much of the time as possible will give you a richer API to work with.

Now Luiggi's right in saying that `Date` has `before` and `after` methods, so you *could* just use:

```
Date fromDate = fromPicker.getDate();
Date toDate = toPicker.getDate();
if (toDate.before(fromDate)) {
    // Show an error message
}
```

I would personally probably convert to `LocalDate` (assuming these really are just dates) as early as possible - probably with methods in your form:

```
// You'd have methods in your form to convert fromPicker.getDate() to LocalDate
// and likewise toPicker.
LocalDate fromDate = getFromDate();
LocalDate toDate = getToDate();
if (toDate.isBefore(fromDate)) {
    // Show an error message
}
```

... again, that's a matter of getting to the preferred representation (a Joda Time one) as early as possible. It's arguably overkill in this particular scenario, but only having to deal with *one* representation for all business logic helps to keep things simple.

I'd also recommend setting the time zone of the date picker to UTC, given that you're only picking dates - if you use UTC for *all* the conversions around this, it'll make it easier to avoid problems depending on where your code is running.

Comment: now I feel if I do much of the changes in code then their will be problem for me so, I want the solutions for the existing problem, I want to compare to date in string format and check if one of the date is greater or not.

Comment: @Mayur: *Why*? What possible benefit is there? You can see how simple it is to compare the dates in a "native" representation - it will be *more* complicated to do so in string form... and you'd be moving your code even further away from the "good" code which only uses strings when it needs to. The more you do that, the less likely it is that you'll *ever* fix it. There's absolutely *nothing* in your problem description that suggests that using a string is called for.

Comment: I will try what you have told me to implement in my code, But tell me then what changes should I make in my database. I have stored my date in String type amd using mysql for database. I have to change the type in Date or datetime ??

Comment: I am getting my date as follows in my code.
'to.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      toDate = formater.format(to.getDate());
      System.out.println(toDate);
     }
    });'

Comment: @Mayur: You don't *have* to change your database format, but I'd strongly *advise* you to. Your data simply *isn't* text data, so why would you treat it that way? Dates and times are frankly hard enough to deal with anyway, without adding the extra complexity of unnecessary conversions. Is this a real project you'll have to maintain, or just a school project? Because if it's a real project, you should weigh up the up-front costs of spending more time to get it right now against the difficulty of fixing it later when you've got production data.

Comment: its a real project, so I was thinking of making the changes now itself. Also I have one more question which I will put up in sometime, is that how do I create my java project as a installable and executable project that can be installed and used at the client site.

Comment: @Mayur: Definitely worth doing that as another question - after checking whether it's already been asked (which I suspect).

Comment: when I select date from JXDatePicker I get in this format
`Thu Mar 21 00:00:00 IST 2013` So I am converting it into 2013-03-21 this format to save it in database as String. Now i tried doing it using date. As follows 

Date fd = (Date) from.getDate();
I am getting error

Comment: @Mayur: No, you get it as a `Date`. A `Date` doesn't *logically* have any format. Sure, if you use `toString()` you get that result, but that isn't really the format of what's returned from the date picker. Unfortunately we can't really help you with a problem as vague as "I am getting error". That could mean anything. Again, I suggest you ask a separate question for that aspect - with a *lot* more detail.

Comment: I will put up the question with all the errors coming up in eclipse.

Comment: @Mayur: Well the exception is self-explanatory: the picker returns a `java.util.Date`, and you're trying to cast it to `java.sql.Date`. That isn't going to work. You'll need to create a new `java.sql.Date` from the existing `java.util.Date` object.